# Elasticsearch should i use both index and analyzer when mapping

Tags: php, search, laravel, elasticsearch

I am not sure on how to map ES the right way for my Laravel app. Do I need both analyzer and index set?

eg:

index: analyzed or not_analyzed
analyzer: standard

Also, when I want integers and dates to be searchable/filtered, is index - not_analyzed enough?

Eg:

string mapping:

type: string
index: analyzed
analyzer: standard

date:

type: date
index: not_analyzed

Its unclear to me if I need to use both

index: analyzed
and
analyzer:standard

or if it is enought to just set index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you gone through the ES documentation for mapping, analysis ? 
There is a pretty good documentation which explains when and why you should be using index analyzers and query analyzers.

ES will dynamically index all your fields and will use default analyzers for indexing and querying, so you should be good if you don't specify these mapping, unless you want to use specific analyzers for your text fields or different analyzers for indexing and querying.

This doc explains  behavior for all the supported data types:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html

Analyzers and Mapping.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-analysis.html

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html

Comment: Thanks @skgemini , so if I got it right. If I want to store integers/dates and make them searchable I only need to set the index as not_analyzed. And eg analyzer: standard should only be used on strings that I want to store and be searchable? Since only strings gets broken down into tokens.

Comment: You don't need to set anything for number or date if you wan't them to be searchable. You set index:no only if you don't want them to be searchable. Analyzers are applicable only for string type fields.http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html